# Gmail signature not present when opening from a mailto link

Tags: gmail, signature, mailto

At first glance this looks like a duplicate of [Gmail signature not working on mailto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660879/gmail-signature-not-working-on-mailto), but it isn't:  In that other question, the problem was due to the mailto link specifying a "body" attribute, so gmail uses that as the body, instead of the usual blank-with-a-signature default body.  That seems reasonable, as a behaviour.

In my case (and others I've tested it with), clicking on **any** mailto link (including ones that just have the email address, and no other attributes) will open a new email in Gmail, but the email will not have the signature.

Is this a known bug with Gmail?  I'm using Version 67.0.3396.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)

EDIT:  Yes, it's a known bug.  See comments below.

Comment: Funny that one of my customers just asked the same thing yesterday, and I could also confirm this behaviour. I don't know if it's the default or a bug, but I'll go ahead an open a case with Google Support, and update this question accordingly.

Comment: Google Support just answered (it was fast) the following: "The bahaviour you describe is an ongoing issue that the Engineering Team is already investigating. For now, we don't have an ETA for the fix."

Comment: Oh, thanks for doing that!

Comment: 4 years later still the same issue